# CSS resize: drag vertical border?

Tags: css, resize

```
div {
   resize: horizontal;
}
```

Users have to drag the bottom right corner to resize it. But for website layout, users are used to drag the left/right edge(border) on the navigation panel. For example, border layout.

```
div {
   resize: horizontal right
}
```

Is there any CSS equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CSS and the `resize` property will not allow for placing the handle on a certain location. It will always be in the bottom-right corner.

If you want to place the handle in a specific location, you may want to use a Javascript library or jQuery plugin, such as the [jQuery UI Resizable plugin](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/).

```js
$(".resizable").resizable({
  handles: {
    'e': '.grip'
  }
});
```

```css
.resizable {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.resizable textarea {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 6px);
  resize: none;
}

.resizable .grip {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  right: -5px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="resizable">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="grip ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: resize symbol is at right bottom, not at right edge.

Comment: My apologies, I completely misread your question. I've changed my answer accordingly.